# Bind CommandParameter from ContextMenu in DataTemplate and ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itemscontrol

In my viewmodel, I have an `ObservableCollection` which holds elements of the type `VaultViewModel`. My view binds to this collection using an `ItemsControl`. Because I also want to display one additional item of the type `NewVault`, I implemented it like this:

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="VaultsCollection" Source="{Binding VaultViewModels}"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:VaultViewModel>
        ... data template for my vaults
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:NewVault>
        ... data template for the additional item
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Resources>

<ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource VaultsCollection}}"/>
        <models:NewVault/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
```

In my DataTemplate for the elements of the type `VaultViewModel`, I have a `Canvas` which displays a `ContextMenu` when left-clicking on it:

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>                    
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">                                                                       
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit..."/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                                  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=icMain}, Path=DataContext.DeleteVaultCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```

In my `MenuItem` I am binding to a command which is implemented in my viewmodel. The command is being executed but I have problems binding the `CommandParameter`.

I want to pass the current element of the `ItemsControl` which is a `VaultViewModel` using `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, but the parameter of the command is `null` and there is no error in the console. My question is how I pass the current element of the `ItemsControl` as the `CommandParameter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by implementing a proxy in the resources of the `Canvas` which holds the `DataContext`. After that, I can use the proxy as a `StaticResource` for the `CommandParameter`:

```
<Canvas.Resources>
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="DataContextProxy" Value="{Binding}"/>
</Canvas.Resources>

<MenuItem ... CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"/>
```

The parameter will be of type `System.Windows.Media.Animation.DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` which holds the `DataContext` in its property `Value`.

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer once you found it. You could also try CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=NameOfItemControlElement}"